# "Force" User Input and Checking for correct Input Type

Tags: types, input, python-3.x, eval

I have some functions calling for user input, sometimes string, int or whatever. so i noticed that if ENTER is pressed with NO INPUT i get an error. SO i did some research and i think i found that EVAL function may be what I'm looking for, but then again i read about its dangers.

SO here are my questions:

1. How can i check/force user input? EX: repeating the input string or maybe even warning user that he didn't enter anything?
2. how do i check for the correct type of input (int, float, string, etc) against whatever the user types without having my scripts returning errors?

I appreciate your feedback,

Cheers

Comment: Combine exception handling and loops... I think `eval` will not help you at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1: enter pressed when prompted for input results in an empty string returned (are you using input() in your scripts?). Apparently empty string is not a valid input for your functions. For all I know, whatever you enter as the input, you end up with a string returned by input(). To check if a string is empty and repeat the prompt, you may try:

```
while True:
    answer = input('Enter something: ')
    if answer: break
```

And for question 2: for checking the type of argument provided, generally the Pythonic way is to handle it with try/except and not check explicitly for each valid/non-valid type. Also, in this scenario you have to do explicit manual conversion from string, so you only check the contents of the string, not deal with other types (at least not yet).  Because of than, you might be interested in string methods or re (regular expressions) module for checking if some particular substring is present (or not).

[re module for python3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html) and 
[string methods for python3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)
For other versions of python, just select an appropriate value in the menu in the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks Mate, I looked for exception handlers and so on and got what i wanted, good suggestion! As for the first point about "forcing" user input your script works like a charm. But could you please translate it to English for me please? if answer: break means something like if there is input for answer break loop, right? but does break HAVE to be next to (:) or can it be below as usual? isn't no input interpreted as input (blank string), in which case why does it work?

Comment: @Newbie break may be in the standard indented block of code, and it is only coded like that (as in my answer above) in very simple cases, but then, for all I know, it's common use to have it in one line. `if answer:` checks if `answer` is True - for Python object truth tests, see http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html - non-empty string is `True`, empty is `False`, so if the string is non-empty it breaks the loop. You could use `if len(answer) != 0:`, but there is no need for that in Python in most cases.

Comment: @Newbie and for the indentation of `break` in this case - iirc, you can have only non-compound statements in the same line as loop header, e.g. `while True: print('something')` and not a nested `if` or `for` in the same line (without a proper indentation block).

Answer (score 1):

A reject all input unless of the correct type:

```py
input_ = input('Enter some input: ')
try:
    input_ = int(input_) # or float(input_); str format is used with input() function by default
except ValueError: # can't convert
    pass # or some other friendly error message
```

To prevent empty inputs:

```py
while True:
    input_ = input('Enter something: ')
    if input_: # if this value is not empty, for example None or ''
        break
pass # continue the program
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second part of the question you can use the `isinstance()` function in python to check if a variable is of a certain type.

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what i was looking for but still good to know. The problem with this solution is that i still have to explicitly turn the input into int, float, etc which means i would get and error if i try turning a str into an int, for example. therefore i still have to use the exception handlers mentioned in the answer above. what i mean is that i tried for a couple hrs using isinstance to implement similar results like with try/except with no good results, sigh! thanks again, still good to enrich the knowledge.